# How to track the use of a variable in a piece of code?

Tags: python

I have a special task which requires me to track the use of an arbitrary variable in any piece of python code. I need to obtain the following information in a tree structure recursively:

1. What functions are using this variable.
2. What variables are referencing or being a copy of this variable.
3. The functions calling the functions in 1 and variables referencing the variables in 2.

For example, in the following piece of code:

```
a=1

b=a

def funA(a):
    print(a)

def funB():
    funA(a)

def funC():
    print(b)
```

The tracking record of the use of global variable a is:

```
a------b
   |   |
   |   |---print
   |         |
   |         |---funC
   |
   |---print
        |
        |---funA
              |
              |---funB
```

I am wondering if there is an existing tool out there I can use for this task. If there are no such tools, what background knowledge should I learn first to build such a tool. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if `funA`'s argument was called `c`? In that case you'd have another "variable" to keep track of

Comment: The problem with your example is that python does not copy variables the sam way another languges do, a = b makes it so that b is pointing to the same memory space that a is using, so for python they are the same variable.

Comment: Are you trying to track this during execution or do you just want to read through all your modules and build the tree from the static code?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here, but an important question to ask yourself is whether you want to do this statically, without running the Python code, or dynamically, while the code is running. Static analysis in Python, especially untyped python, is very difficult because of its dynamic nature. On the other hand, dynamic analysis will only show you code paths that get executed. If you have good test coverage that can help—running your tests will cause most of your code to run and analysis can be done then.

Comment: @DeepSpace, thanks for your reply. When passing the argument, if the variable is already being tracked, I need to keep tracking it. In your case, if funA is being called and the value being passed is related to variable a, we need to track it.

Comment: @wwii, not in the execution, I need to extract the tree structure from static code and do some evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You can, but you're going to have to write something that looks a lot like a compiler. You might get away with "merely" writing a parser for python and doing some static analysis on where symbols are used in which scope for the calculation of which other symbols. However as others have mentioned the dynamic nature of python will be the cause of serious headaches if that analysis has to be complete. You will run into situations that static analysis can't do at all, no matter how clever the program.

Generally you can expect a lot of work to get something working at all and even more work to cover all the different clever uses of python that someone will have done somewhere, that cause your program to run into errors at best and produce subtly wrong output at worst. There's nothing quite as a bad as a bug, that's not a bug, in a compiler, that's not a compiler.